# SQL Server - inserir dados após comparação de 2 tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Tenho 2 tabelas onde quero comparar o preço de produtos:

TABELA: PRODUTO

```
produto  preco
    A     4.5
    B     6 
    C     10
```

TABELA: RANGE PREÇO

```
produto    valor minimo    valor maximo
A            3.2            6.7
B            2.1            4.5 
C            null           null
```

Gostaria de comparar a coluna preço com os valores mínimos e máximos da tabela Comparação. Se o valor estiver dentro do range ou os dados de comparação forem nulos , quero incluir esse valor em uma terceira tabela . Já se o valor estiver fora do range, gostaria de substituir por 0 e também adicionar uma flag na tabela final. Nesse exemplo a tabela final ficaria assim:

TABELA: FINAL

```
produto    preco final      flag
A            4.5            0
B            0              1 
C            10             0
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?
Já tentei fazer um join com condicional e não consegui, não sei se esse é o caminho correto

Comment: olá Lilian, sua pergunta parece muito ampla, tem ai um HTML, até comparar e inserir no SQL tem muitos passos, já tem algo freito de código? qual linguagem está usando?

Comment: Oi Ricardo, começando agora a mexer no stackoverflow... Arrumei as tabelas, agora acho que estão visíveis... Estou trabalhando com SQL server, já tentei fazer join com case, mas na verdade não consegui rodar..

Comment: já conseguiu resolver? poste o código atual pra tentarmos ajustar..

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro realizar o comando `case ... when` para gerar as colunas de resultado que precisa, visto que poderá realizar as verificações no `when` conforme exemplo:

```
Select * into Final from (
SELECT p.produto, 
  case 
    when ((preco >= valor_minimo) and  (preco <= valor_maximo)) 
      or ((valor_minimo is null) and  (valor_maximo is null)) then preco
    when (preco < valor_minimo or preco > valor_maximo) then 0  
  End as preco_final,
  case 
    when ((preco >= valor_minimo) and  (preco <= valor_maximo)) 
      or ((valor_minimo is null) and  (valor_maximo is null)) then 0
    when (preco < valor_minimo or preco > valor_maximo) then 1  
  End as flag
  FROM PRODUTO p LEFT JOIN range_preco r on p.produto = r.produto
) Consulta_Produto_Em_Range
```

No exemplo, estamos criando uma nova tabela chamada `Final` que conterá o resultado da consulta que está nomeada de `Consulta_Produto_Em_Range`.

Caso a tabela de destino `Final` já exista, poderá usar o comando seguinte para **incluir** o resultado da consulta na tabela `Final`:

```
insert into Final 
SELECT p.produto, 
  case 
    when ((preco >= valor_minimo) and  (preco <= valor_maximo)) 
      or ((valor_minimo is null) and  (valor_maximo is null)) then preco
    when (preco < valor_minimo or preco > valor_maximo) then 0  
  End as Preco_Final,
  case 
    when ((preco >= valor_minimo) and  (preco <= valor_maximo)) 
      or ((valor_minimo is null) and  (valor_maximo is null)) then 0
    when (preco < valor_minimo or preco > valor_maximo) then 1  
  End as flag
  FROM PRODUTO p LEFT JOIN range_preco r on p.produto = r.produto
```

Você pode usar a estrutura do `case ... when` para incluir inúmeras condições, caso precise.